# Intercepting unimplemented interface method with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Let's have simple interface:

```java
public interface Person {

    String getFirstName();
    void setFirstName(String firstName);
    
}
```

Now I create proxy this way:

```java
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Class<?> proxy = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).implement(Person.class)
            // AND INTERCEPTS ALL ABSTRACT AND OBJECT DEFAULT METHODS
            // AND TRAP ALL METHODS EXCEPT CONSTRUCTORS AND FINALIZER
            .method(
                ElementMatchers.isAbstract()
            )
            // AND DELEGATE CALL TO OUR INVOCATION HANDLER STORED IN PRIVATE FIELD OF THE CLASS
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Delegator.class))
            // NOW CREATE THE BYTE-CODE
            .make()
            // AND LOAD IT IN CURRENT CLASSLOADER
            .load(TestClass.class.getClassLoader())
            // RETURN
            .getLoaded();

        final Person theInstance = (Person) proxy.newInstance();
        theInstance.setFirstName("ABC");
        theInstance.getFirstName();
    }

    public static class Delegator {

        @RuntimeType
        public static Object intercept(@This Object proxy, @Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Intercept A: " + proxy + ", " + method + ", " + args);
            return null;
        }

        @RuntimeType
        public static Object intercept(@This Object proxy, @Origin Method method) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Intercept B: " + proxy + ", " + method);
            return null;
        }

        @RuntimeType
        public static Object interceptE(@This Object proxy, @DefaultMethod(nullIfImpossible = true) Method defaultMethod, @SuperMethod(nullIfImpossible = true) Method superMethod) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Intercept C: " + proxy + ", " + defaultMethod + ", " + superMethod);
            return null;
        }

        @RuntimeType
        public static Object interceptE(@This Object proxy, @DefaultMethod(nullIfImpossible = true) Method defaultMethod, @SuperMethod(nullIfImpossible = true) Method superMethod, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Intercept D: " + proxy + ", " + defaultMethod + ", " + superMethod + ", " + args);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

When I execute the test I see this output:

```
Intercept C: net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object$ByteBuddy$MVjuc1JA@147ed70f, null, null
Intercept C: net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object$ByteBuddy$MVjuc1JA@147ed70f, null, null
```

It seems that I cannot ever access method signature of the called method if it originates in interface and is not implemented by the superclass?!

Also I would expect that when I call `theInstance.setFirstName("ABC");` I would see `Intercept D:` which also accepts all input arguments.

What do I miss here? I read the documentation but I'm still confused.

In general I want to create `Delegator` that catches all methods in proxied class and handles following situtations:

- do something and then propagate call to the original method
- do something and return it's own result without calling original mehod

For this I would need access to the:

- proxy instance
- called method
- arguments
- a way how to invoke the original method body (if it's not abstract)

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auch - the problem is that some annotations are declared twice in ByteBuddy in different packages - for example:

```
net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments
net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.AllArguments
```

When annotation from the `implementation` package is used, everything works. That's a nasty catch!

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunate. The original idea was to align them in order to simplify migration, but when using class member imports, this is non-intuitive. I never use that, so it did not occur to me at that time and now it's too late to change this without breaking binary compatibility.